# How to get a download link which requires checkboxes checking in additional dialog box

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, download

I want to download the last publicly available file from https://sam.gov/data-services/Exclusions/Public%20V2?privacy=Public

while trying to download manually, the real download links look like:

https://falextracts.s3.amazonaws.com/Exclusions/Public%20V2/SAM_Exclusions_Public_Extract_V2_22150.ZIP?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220530T143743Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=2699&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAY3LPYEEXWOQWHCIY%2F20220530%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=3eca59f75a4e1f6aa59fc810da8f391f1ebfd8ca5a804d56b79c3eb9c4d82e32

My function gets only initial link, which refers to the real link:

```
import json
import requests
from operator import itemgetter


files_url = 'https://sam.gov/api/prod/fileextractservices/v1/api/listfiles?random=1653676394983&domain=Exclusions/Public%20V2&privacy=Public'

def get_file():
    response = requests.get(files_url, stream=True)
    links_resp = json.loads(response.text)
    links_dicts = [d for d in links_resp['_embedded']['customS3ObjectSummaryList'] if d['displayKey'].count('SAM_Exclus')]
    sorted_links = sorted(links_dicts, key=itemgetter('dateModified'), reverse=True)
    return sorted_links[0]['_links']['self']['href']

get_file()
```

Result:

```
'https://s3.amazonaws.com/falextracts/Exclusions/Public V2/SAM_Exclusions_Public_Extract_V2_22150.ZIP'
```

But by following the above link, I get **Access denied**

So I will appreciate any hints on how to get real download links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited your code as much as possible so you can understand. The requests library can convert it to json itself.

imports that are not at the beginning of the code do not look very good for reading...

```
import requests as req
from operator import itemgetter

files_url = "https://sam.gov/api/prod/fileextractservices/v1/api/listfiles?random=1653676394983&domain=Exclusions/Public%20V2&privacy=Public"
down_url = "https://sam.gov/api/prod/fileextractservices/v1/api/download/Exclusions/Public%20V2/{}?privacy=Public"

def get_file():
    response = req.get(files_url, stream=True).json()

    links_dicts = [d for d in response["_embedded"]["customS3ObjectSummaryList"]]
    sorted_links = sorted(links_dicts, key=itemgetter('dateModified'), reverse=True)

    key = sorted_links[0]['displayKey']
    
    down = req.get(down_url.format(key))

    if not down.status_code == 200:
        return False

    print(key)
    open(key, 'wb').write(down.content)
    
    return True

get_file()
```

Comment: I mean this way is correct. maybe the best way. I wanted to say that I have edited it in a way that you can understand so you can ask if there is something you do not understand in the code.

Comment: yes we can download file without get Access Denied

Comment: Yes, actually, it downloads the file. I was not saving the file. I was passing download link to crawler's function and that function got access denied. Thanks!